# How to make translucent scrollbar with css

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanna customize scrollbar like [this website](https://beta.reactjs.org) in Chrome. So far, I used `-webkit-scrollbar`, but I cannot make the similar one. What I want is that when we dont use scrollbar, it is hidden. If we scroll page or hover the scrollbar, I wanna show the bar. the bar color is gray and background color is translucent.The color changes in light mode and dark mode.  How can I make that kind of scrollbar with CSS in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme is helpful to make scrollbar adopt dark mode and light mode